# Terminal services printers/scanners?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, printing

Is there some list of printers/scanners that are known to work with Terminal Services or some way to determine automatically if the device will work from the specifications?

I am needing to advise a customer on a small(as in, can set on a desk) all-in-one printer/scanner/fax that works with Terminal Services.

The client OS is Windows XP, the server OS is Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no one "source" of information for this. We usually use two criteria to determine if a printer will work on our W2K3 TS:

1. The printer vendor must have a W2K3 driver.
2. The printer must support PCL, as opposed to GDI or LIDL.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically support all printers and scanners on your remote desktop server by using third party software. All around packages for both printing and scanning are available from tricerat and terminalworks. We are using [TerminalWorks TSScan](http://www.terminalworks.com/tsscan.php) and [TerminalWorks TSPrint](http://www.terminalworks.com/tsprint.php) as both are pretty cheap compared to tricerat screwdrivers or thinprint which doesn't even have a scanning solution (or at least didn't have it the last time i checked).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to joeqwerty's good answer, if you need scanner support, check Microsoft's advice here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555969

When I've had to deal with existing printers that have poor support in Terminal Services on Windows 2003, I've had success with the [ThinPrint .print](http://www.thinprint.com/Products/ProductFinder/Features/MSTSRemoteDesktopServices.aspx) application.

Answer (score 0):

As for brands, you can't go wrong with any HP's network printers/all-in-ones.